# Dynamic display of images with transition after loading

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract the onload event after loading the image to get a smooth transition to the appearance of pictures. Otherwise, the css script is applied to images that have not yet been downloaded. How can this be done?

```
let func = new IntersectionObserver( (a, b) => {
        a.forEach( x => {
            if (x.isIntersecting) {
                x.target.style = x.target.dataset.style;
                if (x.target.style.onload) {
                    x.target.removeAttribute('data-style');
                }
                b.unobserve(x.target);
            }
        })
    }
```

```
//HTML
<a href=“url.html” data—style=“background-image: url’url.jpg’”>
```

```
//CSS
a[data-style] {
opacity: 0
}
a[style] {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 1s
}
```

Comment: Hey, where is the answer that was given to the question before? It was an excellent answer!

Comment: It was deleted 23 hours ago by Henry Ecker♦. But i cant really see why

Comment: Now i see, the user that posted the answer was suspended for rule violations

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to extract the event after it is called, one way to do that would be to create it as an `addEventListener` and then remove it like this:

```
const image = document.getElementById("image");

function imageLoaded() {
  console.log("Image loaded!");
}

image.addEventListener("load", imageLoaded);

// ...

image.removeEventListener("load", imageLoaded);
```